# What is the symmetry group of $(z, z^*) \in\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: group-theory, rotations

I'm curious about the symmetry group of $(z, z^*)\in\mathbb{C}^2$; that is, the complex vector in $\mathbb{C}^2$ consisting of a complex number and it's conjugate.

The first thing I though of was to explicitly construct the symmetry matrices that left this quantity invariant. So for $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}$, we want to try and satisfy the condition

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}a &b\\c&d\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}z\\z^*\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}z\\z^*\end{array}\right)$$

such that $ad-cb\neq0$ (so that the transformation is invertible). Besides the identity matrix, one can find some particular equations that must be satisfied by the matrix, but they don't suggest any particular properties (like orthogonality or unitarity):

$$(a-1)(d-1)=bc.$$

Thinking about this more intuitively, if you're fixing a particular vector in $\mathbb{C}^2\simeq\mathbb{R}^4$ and considering transformations that leave it invariant, I think the answer might just be rotations of a 3-sphere $\mathbb{S}^3$, so the matrices above might just be representations of $SO(3)$.

Can anyone help confirm or correct either of those two approaches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer the question in your body text first, that is, what are all the *complex* $2 \times 2$ matrices such that

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}a &b\\c&d\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}z\\z^*\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}z\\z^*\end{array}\right)$$

for *all* complex numbers $z$?

The answer is "Only the identity matrix". Notice that your matrix $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a &b\\c&d\end{array}\right)$ has to fix both of the complex vectors $\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{c}i\\-i\end{array}\right)$, but these form a basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$, and so $A$ must in fact fix all of $\mathbb{C}^2$, i.e., it is the identity matrix.

The fundamental reason for this is that complex conjugation is *not* a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map, and so you're asking for matrices that fix a non-linear subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ given by $z_2 = z_1^*$, and so it's not surprising that only the identity works.

However, your title question and last paragraph suggest that you're not really interested in this space as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$, but maybe just as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$, and here, it *is* a (real)-linear subspace! So let's recast the question.

$\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^4$ via the map $(x+iy,z+iw) \mapsto (x,y,z,w)$, and so we're looking for elements $A \in GL(4,\mathbb{R})$ that satisfy

$$A \left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y \\ x \\ -y\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y \\ x \\ -y\end{array}\right),$$ i.e., that fix the linear subspace $W$ given by the equations $z = x, w = -y$.

This subspace $W$ has basis $\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right),  \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{array}\right)\right\}$, which can be extended to an (orthogonal) basis $\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right),  \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right)\right\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

With respect to this basis, $A$ changes to:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 \ 0 \ a \ b\\ 0 \ 1 \ c\ d\\ 0 \ 0 \ e\ f\\ 0 \ 0 \ g\ h\end{array}\right)$$

with $eh - fg \neq 0$.

This is because $A$ must leave $W$ invariant and act as the identity there. If you want a name for this subgroup, it's isomorphic to the semidirect product $M(2,\mathbb{R}) \rtimes GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ under left multiplication.

Edit: I see now that you may have been asking the question for only one particular vector $(z, z^*)$ and not all vectors of this form. But then it really isn't like orthogonal or unitary matrices at all, which have to fix entire invariants of vectors (like length or angle). In any case, for *any* non-zero vector in $\mathbb{C}^2$, by extending it to a basis as I did above, we can see that the matrices that fix it are (with respect to that basis)

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 \ b\\ 0 \ d\end{array}\right)$$

with $ d \neq 0$.

If you want a name for *this* subgroup, it's isomorphic to the semidirect product $M(1,\mathbb{C}) \rtimes GL(1,\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C} \rtimes \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ under left multiplication.

The place I think you're confused is the difference between a point and a vector. If you're looking for all Eucldiean symmetries (isometries) that fix a point in $\mathbb{R}^4$, then that stabilizer is isomorphic to SO(3), regardless of the form of the point. But you asked to fix a *vector*, which by linearity fixes an entire line, so the answer is different.

Comment: From how I understood the question, it is about the subset of $\operatorname{GL}(2,\Bbb C)$ fixing one vector $(z,z^*)$ for fixed $z\in\Bbb C$.

Comment: I see that interpretation now. But then there's no real analogy to orthogonal or unitary matrices if you're only fixing one particular vector. It's also then a red herring that the vector is of the form (z, z*), since the answer is the same for *any* fixed non-zero vector. The subgroup is just $GL(1,\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Is it? Fixing $e_1\in\Bbb C^2$ should be all matrices $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&b\\0&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ with $b,d\in\Bbb C$ and $d\neq 0$. For arbitrary $v\in \Bbb C^2$ you conjugate by some invertible matrix.

Comment: You're right. I'm mixing my requirements in that I wanted orthogonality to be preserved, but then the groups should be O instead of GL. It's not clear if the OP demanded these maps to be isometries or not.

Comment: I very much appreciate the demonstration of the difference between the real and complex case - in truth, I may be interested in both since this is a physical problem, and part of what I'm having to choose is real vs complex matrices. And I'm not interested in the maps being isometries unless it turns out that's what's required to answer the question....sounds like it's not.'

Comment: ...further, I guess I am confused about points vs vectors, but my real analogy might have just gotten away from me. Rotations of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are equivalent to rotations about a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (I think), so I thought rotations about a particular vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ would be equivalent to rotations of the 3-sphere. ...

Comment: ...more further, I guess I want transformations which $(z~z^*)$ invariant for all $z$. If I multiply your matrix by $(z~z^*)$, this only happens when b=0 and d=1. So guess the answer is the identity. Too bad, but I think that just means I need to consider the real case more carefully.

Comment: Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^4$ are not about vectors, but about planes. Just like how rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ fix a point and in $\mathbb{R}^3$ fix a line.

Comment: Anyway, "rotation" usually means an element of SO(n), and in particular an isometry. So any element of SO(4) is also a "rotation" of the 3-sphere, but it doesn't necessarily look like a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$.